# Extjs - newbie, Switch case function not working

Tags: extjs

In this following code I am getting the desired output

```
fn: function(btn) {
switch(btn){
case 'yes':
Ext.Msg.prompt('Milton', 'Where is it?');
break;
case 'no':
Ext.Msg.alert('Milton',
'Im going to burn the building down!');
break;
case 'cancel':
Ext.Msg.wait('Saving tables to disk...','File Copy');
break;
}
}
```

This Works just fine. Now i am trying to do a function call in the switch 'yes' but i don't get any output in the screen.
This is the code i am using.

```
case 'yes':
Ext.Msg.prompt('Milton', 'Where is it?', function(btn,txt)
{
if (txt.toLowerCase() == 'the office') {
Ext.get('my_id').dom.innerHTML = 'Dull Work';
}else{
Ext.get('my_id').dom.innerHTML = txt;
}
Ext.DomHelper.applyStyles('my_id',{
background: 'transparent
url(images/stapler.png) 50% 50% no-repeat'
});
});
break;
```

Using this code inside the swich case 'yes' , i am getting a blank screen. Even the dialog box has dissapeared. Please help.

Comment: What is the error you get in the console ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Thanks for the reply. I am not getting any errors in the console. At the very least it should show the dialog box. But all i am getting is a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very basic javascript error. A string cannot extend over the end of the line. This will work.

```
case 'yes':
Ext.Msg.prompt('Milton', 'Where is it?', function(btn,txt){
    if (txt.toLowerCase() == 'the office') {
        Ext.get('my_id').dom.innerHTML = 'Dull Work';
    }else{
        Ext.get('my_id').dom.innerHTML = txt;
    }
    Ext.DomHelper.applyStyles('my_id',{
        background: 'transparent url(images/stapler.png) 50% 50% no-repeat'
    });
});
break;
```

In the console I got the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: Again : what is the error in the console ?
(recommendation : use Chrome Devtools)

Comment: It works for me. You might want to add `console.log` to prove that `Ext.Msg.prompt` is really called.